# error in gitlab cicd test stage - no module find even though file is present

Tags: python, gitlab, fastapi, relative-path

________________________ ERROR collecting test_main.py _________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/builds/project/test_main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_main.py:4: in 
from .main import app
main.py:16: in 
from addons.utility import config
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'addons'

### main.py

from addons.utility import config

### project structure

|-- main.py

|-- test_main.py

|-- addons (package)

```
|-- utility.py
```